# Updating n-th column in csv using awk

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

Input file

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100
111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1000
```

Expected Output

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8MNINS,9,10
11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88MNINS,99,100
111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888MNINS,999,1000
```

I tried the following command

```
awk -F "," '{$8=$8"MNINS"}1' 1.csv > 2.csv
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8MNINS 9 10
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88MNINS 99 100
111 222 333 444 555 666 777 888MNINS 999 1000
```

It is removed all the commas, so my csv file is changing into space seperated file.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify comma as Output field separator value.

```
awk -F "," -v OFS="," '{$8=$8"MNINS"}1' 1.csv > 2.csv
```

Comment: SaY in the form of accept http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer